# Разбить название полученных файлов на части

Tags: php

Используя `scahdir`, я получаю содержимое директории. У каждого файла ФИО.расширение. Как получить из названия Фамилию, Имя, Отчество и расширение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дружище, держи https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.directoryiterator.php и не благодари.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php
$bz = scandir('./img');
foreach ($bz as $key){
    $keyZ = explode('.', $key);
    $keyY = explode(' ', $keyZ[0]);
    echo 'Фамилия - '.$keyY[0].'<br>';
    echo 'Имя - '.$keyY[1].'<br>';
    if(count($keyY) > 2){ // Если больше двух элементо, значит есть отчество.
        echo 'Отчество - '.$keyY[0].'<br>';
    }
    echo 'Тип документа - '.$key[1];
}
```